# CSS external links are displayed inside body tag instead of head tag

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, web-inspector

Am giving all my css external links inside the head tag.But when I inspect the webpage all css links are appeared inside the body tag instead of displayed in head tag.What am doing wrong?

Comment: Show the problem

Comment: please show some screen shot or error code

Comment: I think you've probably got 2 heads. Are you including anything via php?

Comment: it's easy. check my answer. but if still not solved, please paste your source code of page via browser (Cntrl + U)

Comment: And also at the second image(inspect),why the empty space is taken after body tag?But i didn't give any space there:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your base url in links in head you have double quotes `""` because you have double quotes all ready wrapped around it use single quotes inside `base_url('')`

```
href="<?php echo base_url("something.css");?>"
```

change like to single quote in base url

```
href="<?php echo base_url('something.css');?>"
```

Make sure you autoload the url helper config/autoload.php

Also make sure you have set your base url in config.php **IS A MUST**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';
```

Or a domain some thing like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your quotes and apostrophes.

Because you are using quotes inside href quotes the markup is breaking, causing a browser to *guess* at proper markup.

You can't use `<link href="<?php base_url("foo bar") ?>">` -- All those quotes count as quotes.

Switch to apostrophes for something, such as `<link href="<?php base_url('foo bar') ?>">` or `<link href='<?php base_url("foo bar") ?>'>`

Comment: I think you are wrong. Why would quotes for a php printed/echoed string have any bearing on the rendered html page?

Comment: @Doug You are free to test yourself. Heh.. note other answers are *repeating* my answer.

Comment: Doesn't mean either of you are right. Just equally wrong. His code show's a head is added, with a cloud front script thrown in. The fact he has a head show's he's attempting to add 2 heads. Obviously the second gets ignored and turned into a body. Find where the Cloudfront script is getting added and you'll find the cause.

Comment: @Doug.. you can **easily** test this yourself you know. *Quotes do matter*.

Comment: Of course quotes matter. But quotes in PHP do not affect quotes in html and vise versa. Unless he was printing the entire html markup within his php. Which he is not. Therefore the php is parsed and echoed right where he asks it to, without the quotes... Because that is how it works 

Answer (score 1):

Base on screenshot you're provided. There's have a unclosed tag inside your `<head></head>`.

Please make sure your HTML tag in head a closed. Contains `<link/>`, `<script><script/>`, `<meta/>`, `<style></style>`, `<title></title>` and etc.

Base on your screenshot, i would suggest to you, try to edit html tag (especially `meta` tag) in your head

`<meta whatever="whatever">` to `<meta whatever="whatever"/>`

`<link whatever="whatever">` to `<link whatever="whatever"/>`